# The Evolution of inverted pendulum is on which Smooth Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, complex-systems

The Dynamical System (Cart& Inverted Pendulum) does it evolves on smooth manifold or Non-smooth manifold? If so, what is the order for this smooth manifold($C^0,C^1,C^n,C^{\infty}$). Please give me a lucid explanation to this, since I am new to this field.